# How are writing shaders different in Unity's scriptable render pipeline vs the standard pipeline?

Tags: unity, shaders

So I want to start learning how to write shaders because the shadergraph seems very limited at the moment. I've done some research and it seems that I should learn the HLSL language which is used by Unity. I'm becoming confused though how this will carry over between pipelines. I read that standard pipeline shaders aren't supported in URP so I'm confused how the shader language is different in URP if they both use the HLSL language. I was wondering if someone with a better grasp on this could explain the difference between them and if the skills carry over, as most tutorials online seem to be for writing shaders in the standard pipeline. Thanks.

Comment: Have you worked your way through [tutorials on the subject](https://catlikecoding.com/unity/tutorials/scriptable-render-pipeline/custom-shaders/)? You can see the language is the same, but some of the macros used are different. Did you run into any particular step that you need help with?

Comment: Hi thanks for the link Gregory this is an amazing resource, I'm going to start following along with it. Would you recommend learning with surface shaders before learning the URP workflow? Surface shaders seem to automate a lot of complex stuff for you.